# Python export to file via ofile without bracket characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I successfully simplified a python module that imports data from a spectrometer
(I'm a total beginner, somebody else wrote the model of the code for me...)

I only have one problem: half of the output data (in a `.csv` file) is surrounded by brackets: `[]`

I would like the file to contain a structure like this:

```
name, wavelength, measurement
```

i.e

```
a,400,0.34
a,410,0.65
...
```

but what I get is:

```
a,400,[0.34]
a,410,[0.65]
...
```

Is there any simple fix for this?

Is it because `measurement` is a `string`?

Thank you

```
import serial  # requires pyserial library

ser  = serial.Serial(0)
ofile = file( 'spectral_data.csv', 'ab')

while True:
    name = raw_input("Pigment name [Q to finish]: ")
    if name == "Q":
        print "bye bye!"
        ofile.close()
        break

    first = True

    while True:
        line = ser.readline()
        if first:
            print "  Data incoming..."
            first = False
        split = line.split()
        if 10 <= len(split):
            try:
                wavelength = int(split[0])
                measurement = [float(split[i]) for i in [6]]
                ofile.write(str(name) + "," + str(wavelength) + "," + str(measurement) + '\n')

            except ValueError:
                pass    # handles the table heading
        if line[:3] == "110":
            break

    print "  Data gathered."
    ofile.write('\n')
```

Comment: what did you try to do on the line `[float(split[i]) for i in [6]]` it is exactly like `[[float(split[6])]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this:

```
measurement = [float(split[i]) for i in [6]]
ofile.write(str(name) + "," + str(wavelength) + "," + ",".join(measurement) + '\n')
```

**OR**

```
ofile.write(str(name) + "," + str(wavelength) + "," + split[6] + '\n')
```

Comment: hi, doesn't works. Are you sure you worte it correctly? What is .join? thanks

Comment: do you mean str.join(measurement)??

Comment: should work, what you get?
`join` takes a list and convert it to a string where the list items separated with the called string, in this case `,`. try it.

Comment: the problem is `measurement`is a float, then instead of getting: `name,wavelength,measurement` the measurement part splits into several commas: `a,400,[2.19]` (previous result) becomes: `a,4002,.,1,9`

Comment: you combined my both suggestions? maybe I wasn't clear. I'll edit the answer

Comment: yes I did, I simplified to `measurement = split[6]` and I put the line `ofile.write(str(name) + "," + str(wavelength) + ",".join(measurement) + '\n')`

Comment: ok, so look now in the answer. and choose one of the ways. second is better